# How to ID all the SSRS reports

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

we have lttle more than 50 SSRS reports. I would like to assign an unique ID to each report.
I am just wondering if there is a way to leverage system generated information somewhere in the SQL-Server (2012) databases rather than manually assigning each report an ID, for example using spreadsheet. 
Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Are you looking for a GUID, integer, or some other type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to assign an Id to your reports I strongly recommend you create one that does NOT relate to the Report Server metadata. For example the ItemID in the Catalog table is a uniqueidentifier data type. This means that if I deleted a report and redeployed it, or deployed it to a different Report Server, the report would get a different ItemID value.

If you want to assign an Id to your reports (which is a good practice, as report names can sometimes change over time) then something like a Sharepoint list or a spreadsheet is a good starting point and 50 reports should be easy to manage that way.

Usually I recommend assigning each report an ID (e.g. "RPT001") and the either include the ID in the report name, or have it displayed somewhere on the report itself. This helps ensure that similarly named reports are not confused and allows tracking of reports if the name of the report changes.

Comment: Useful comments that help give some perspective to my answer - one thing to note is that deploying over an existing version does *not* change the `ItemID`. But as you say other cases (deleting, moving) *will* change this. I think this highlights a lot of the potential issues - maybe it *is* safer to record this information in some sort of CMS type scenario, even a spreadsheet. I guess it all depends on the exact use case.

Comment: Thank you Nathan. I appreciated your suggestion. I like an idea of creating one in the spreadsheet as a starting point.

Answer (score 6):

The SSRS `Catalog` table in the `reportserver` database assigns GUIDs to each report item on the server - would this help?

```
select ItemID, [Path], Name
from [Catalog]
where [Type] = 2
```

These tables aren't strictly documented but they are straightforward enough to understand.

Comment: Thanks Ian as always for helpful suggestion.

Comment: Thanks @Ian Preston. It helped much.

Comment: As I have just discovered the hard way, it appears possible to copy a report to a different location on the same server and it will retain the original id. which has royally stuffed me up iterating the reports on ours.  Use the CatalogItem.ID with caution.

Comment: Further to my last comment, I have discovered this is an issue with using SSRS in integrated mode, one which Microsoft are apparently aware of.  A user can publish the same report via both the cname path and the direct server name path and the report appears to exist twice, with the same "unique" id.  It's a bug.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
select u.username, c.name, s.Description, s.LastStatus 
from Subscriptions s 
join users u on s.OwnerID = u.UserID join catalog c on c.itemid = s.Report_OID
```